# Disabling User Interaction with a segmented control?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to enable and disable user interaction with a UISegmented Control. I noticed that its superclass UIControl has a property called "enabled" is this what I need to set in order to disable/enable my control?

Comment: yeah I just tried it and it work perfectly. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the `enabled` property is what you want.  You can also use `userInteractionEnabled` as well, but I think that `enabled` will suffice.

Comment: I found that `enabled` alone isn't enough. A disabled segmented control will still receive touches and change its segment. It needs the `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO` too.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, for example. You can also use `[segmentedControl setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]`

Answer (score 1):

In swift 4.2

set yourSegmentedControlName.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Answer (score 1):

Upon tapping a segment I was making a network call and during the network call I wanted to disable the segment and also have it greyed out a bit.

Using `isUserInteractionEnabled` will only disable/enable the segment.

But using `isEnabled` will gray and add a gray overlay in addition to disabling/enabling the segment.

So for me `isEnabled` was a better alternative