# How to remove border from segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

How do I remove the outside border of a segmented control? 
I've set the divider image to what I wanted but now to follow the mock of my app I need to have a segmented control without the outer border.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

What you must understand is the `backgroundColor` property is not stateful. 
Hence you have to use [`setBackgroundImage(_:for:barMetrics:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618571-setbackgroundimage).

We can easily remove both borders and dividers using the below function.

**For Swift 3 & 4+:**

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders() {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: backgroundColor ?? .clear), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: tintColor!), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    }

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:  1.0, height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
        context!.fill(rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image!
    }
}
```

---

**For Swift 2.2:**

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders() {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(backgroundColor!), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(tintColor!), forState: .Selected, barMetrics: .Default)
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forLeftSegmentState: .Normal, rightSegmentState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
    }

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image
    }
}
```

Call the above function.

```
segmentedControl.removeBorders()
```

Reference: [Remove UISegmentedControl separators completely. (iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314927/remove-uisegmentedcontrol-separators-completely-iphone)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3921490/amagain for Swift 3 version.

Comment: Thanks :) It worked =D But one more question, this will make my segmented control have a sharp rectangular corner, any ways to make it rounded?

Comment: @Happiehappie no you can't, please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834244/uisegmentedcontrol-without-rounded-corner

Comment: I am getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on line `setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: backgroundColor!), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)`

Comment: You also need to set background color to some color other that `Default` apparently. `backgroundColor` was nil when it was set to `Default`.

Comment: To fix the background nil issue: `setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: backgroundColor ?? .white), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)`

Comment: Doesn't work anymore on iOS13! Have a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450865/uisegmentedcontrol-ios-13-clear-color

Answer (score 12):

Here's the swift 3 version of [Sohil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4710527/sohil-r-memon)'s answer that might help someone else. It did help me. :)

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
func removeBorders() {
    setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: backgroundColor!), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: tintColor!), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
    setDividerImage(imageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
}

// create a 1x1 image with this color
private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:  1.0, height: 1.0)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
    context!.fill(rect);
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope it will help someone

Swift - 4

Make the Background color and Tint color of your Segment control to same color.
Then "set titleTextAttributes" of your Segment control

```
    segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .selected)
```

Comment: If i want different tint color then it will not work.

Comment: Yea correct. This is trick when the backgroundColor and Tint color is same then the borderColor will be same color as TintColor.

Answer (score 2):

If you want save borders between cells

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
  func removeBorders() {
    if let backgroundColor = backgroundColor, let backgroundImage = UIImage.imageWithSize(size: CGSize.one_one, color: backgroundColor){
      setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    }

    if let tintColor = tintColor, let tintImage = UIImage.imageWithSize(size: CGSize.one_one, color: tintColor){
      setBackgroundImage(tintImage, for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        setDividerImage(tintImage, forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    }
  }
}

extension CGSize{
  static var one_one: CGSize{
    return CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
  }
}

extension UIImage{
  static func imageWithSize(size : CGSize, color : UIColor = UIColor.white) -> UIImage? {
    var image:UIImage? = nil
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
      context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
      context.addRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size));
      context.drawPath(using: .fill)
      image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have the usecase where you don't want the rounded border as you don't want to see it if it's embedded in a cell. In this case, set the autolayout constraints to -2 and the border will be hidden as it will extend beyond the cell border.

Answer (score 0):

If you need segment control with texts Only, use,

```
segmentControl.backgroundColor = .clear
segmentControl.tintColor = .clear

let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [.font : UIFont(family: .medium, ofSize: 13)!, .foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)

let selectedAttrib: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [.font : UIFont(family: .medium, ofSize: 13)!, .foregroundColor : UIColor.red]
segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(hightLightedStateAttrib, for: .selected)
```

*NB: I googled it for a long time, thats why i'm posted here.*

Source: [CodeMentor](https://www.codementor.io/kevinfarst/designing-a-button-bar-style-uisegmentedcontrol-in-swift-cg6cf0dok)

Answer (score 0):

- The accepted answer works for getting rid of the border.
- The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56792907/5175709) also works for disabling the segmented Control.

Yet putting the two solutions together, I wasn't able to get the correct *selected* segment  in a `disabled` state.

What I wanted was that upon selecting a segment and making a network call, I wanted to disable the segmented control.

The outcome was like this:

[image]

What was desired was this:

[image]

The only addition to [Sohil's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651983/how-to-remove-border-from-segmented-control/31652184#31652184) is:

```
setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: imageWithColor(color: tintColor)), for: [.selected, .disabled], barMetrics: .default)
```

After the **selected && disabled** segment will have the right color.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5.x:

This solution remove only the external border and preserve the round corner on each button

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders(andBackground:Bool=false) {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: backgroundColor ?? .clear), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: tintColor!), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)

        _ = self.subviews.compactMap {
            if ($0.frame.width>0) {
                $0.layer.cornerRadius = 8
                $0.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                $0.clipsToBounds = true
                $0.layer.borderWidth = andBackground ? 1.0 : 0.0
                $0.layer.borderColor = andBackground ? tintColor?.cgColor : UIColor.clear.cgColor
                andBackground ? $0.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor : nil
            }
        }
    }

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:  1.0, height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
        context!.fill(rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image!
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
mySegmentedControl.removeBorders()
```

Comment: It removes the round corners.

Comment: @RoneySampaio The purpose of this method was to remove  the external round corners, have you read the title and the description? It re-create the round corner to each button inside..

Answer (score 0):

[Sohil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31652184/1260976) did help me.

But if you don't set the `UIImage` size, it may affect the size of the `UISegmentedControl`.

If you also encounter this problem, please consider using the following code.

```
func *(lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: lhs.width * rhs, height: lhs.height * rhs)
}

extension UIImage {
    func resized(_ size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }

    func resized(_ size: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        guard size > 0, self.size.width > 0, self.size.height > 0 else { return nil }
        let ratio = size / max(self.size.width, self.size.height)
        return self.resized(self.size * ratio)
    }

    func refilled(_ color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        color.set()
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }

    public convenience init?(color: UIColor = .clear, size: CGSize) {
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
        context.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size));
        guard let cgImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.cgImage else { return nil }

        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}

extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders() {
        let image = UIImage(size: self.bounds.size)
        self.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setBackgroundImage(image?.refilled(self.tintColor), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setDividerImage(image?.resized(1), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    }
}
```

Easy to use:

```
segmentedControl.removeBorders()
```