# UISegmentedControl Borders/Highlighted State

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

[image: This is the image of my current segmented control, the 2nd section is currently selected.]

I currently have a uisegmentedcontrol element in my VC and have managed to remove the borders by following the thread below. While it works fine, once selected the uisegmentedcontrol section becomes entirely white, including the icon, is there any way to modify that? So the background of the selected section would be whatever colour I specify and the icon becomes white. Thanks in advance for anyone who may help.

The thread mentioned:
[Swift: How to remove border from segmented control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651983/swift-how-to-remove-border-from-segmented-control)

Comment: Can you share code and the screenshot of the SegmentedControl?

Comment: i have added a screenshot with the 2nd section selected, for code please visit the link I posted and the answer for that is the exact code I'm using

Comment: I think you can use selected and unselected state to use different colors

Comment: I've tried that within the code using the .isHighlighted method but nothing. Any other way to get it with no borders and retain the selected colour?

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: do you need something like that : http://imgur.com/a/6HMfi

Comment: exactly like that but in grey

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/FN7lp is this fine?

Comment: or you want the selected indictor to be gray?

Comment: the selected one to be grey, if its not selected than white background but shows icon.

Comment: is this fine? http://imgur.com/a/vhYyf

Comment: That is perfect, can the "3" and "4" be grey aswell or no? and how did you achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can change the background color for selected indicator in `UISegmentControl`

```
extension UISegmentedControl{
    func removeBorders() {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: .clear), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: .gray), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    }

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:  1.0, height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
        context!.fill(rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image!
    }
}
```

As you can see in `removeBorders` function you are setting background image based on color for `normal` and `selected` state. So here you can use whatever color you like.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a shot as soon as I get back to my PC, thanks again!

Comment: Thank its my pleasure :)