# How to set backgroundColor of UISegmentedControl to white in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13

iOS 13 introduced some changes to the UISegmentedControl including a really nice animation when switching the selected segment. However I'm noticing that it's not displaying the `backgroundColor` property correctly, it always seems to have a bit of a tint to it.

I've seen questions that answer how to set the `selectedSegmentTintColor` and such but I'm struggling to set the `backgroundColor` to say `.white`, no matter what I do it always shows up a bit of a gray even though there's no `tintColor` or similar setting applied. Setting the `backgroundColor` to other colors shows the same behavior but its most obvious with white. Adding to the mystery is that while this difference shows up on both iOS 13 simulators and a physical device running iOS 13, the visual debugger (in XCode 11 GM2) does not show this difference!

Here's a couple screenshots showing that even though the `backgroundColor` of the `UISegmentedControl` is set to the same as the `backgroundColor` of the view shown behind it they are slightly different.

Device running iOS 13 (white backgroundColor)
[image]

Same view/code shown in Visual Debugger (white backgroundColor)
[image]

Device running iOS 13 (blue backgroundColor)
[image]

I've tried the suggestion of applying a `backgroundImage` as suggested in this SO post: [UISegmentedControl iOS 13 clear color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450865/uisegmentedcontrol-ios-13-clear-color) but that ends up reverting the style back to how it looked in iOS 12 and you lose the nice animation as well.

Any guidance or suggestions is greatly appreciated! I've also filed a bug report with Apple, will see if anything comes of that.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I'm getting the same

Comment: I have not unfortunately. I opened a bug report with Apple a couple days after posting this question but unfortunately have not gotten any response thus far.

Comment: check my answer below, I resolved my issue this way

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have the same issue and there is no cool way to resolve it. So I did this small workaround. I dont like it and I am not proud of it, but it works.

```
func fixBackgroundSegmentControl( _ segmentControl: UISegmentedControl){
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        //just to be sure it is full loaded
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { 
            for i in 0...(segmentControl.numberOfSegments-1)  {
                let backgroundSegmentView = segmentControl.subviews[i]
                //it is not enogh changing the background color. It has some kind of shadow layer 
                backgroundSegmentView.isHidden = true 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at my answer below, I just found a way to do it that's a little bit cooler than this, even if your way it's working

Comment: This did the trick! I had given up on this entirely, thanks for sharing your solution. Its a bit hacky but given the ridiculousness of the situation at hand it feels appropriate :)

Comment: With this code my segmented control loses text but the gray overlay still presented.

Comment: Using this solution, the dividers between segments disappear in my segmented control. Do you have the same side effect? If not, can you share your configuration of the segmented control?

Comment: this solution is not good for me,  same times tittle disappear :/

Comment: This trick works also using a normal `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:)` instead of a 0.1 second delay using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)`.

Comment: Using this solution, the dividers between segments disappear in my segmented control. Do you have the same side effect? If not, can you share your configuration of the segmented control?

Answer (score 4):

I've found the simplest solution.

```swift
let segmentControl: UISegmentControl = ... 
segmentControl.subviews.forEach { subview in
  subview.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you are losing the selected background color with this solution

Comment: What suggestion how handle that?

Comment: 'selectedSegmentTintColor' not working after such solution.

Comment: Is there a way to do this "subviews" thing in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me (Swift 5).

```
let background = myColors.background
let selectedColor = myColors.foreground

if #available(iOS 13.0, *)
{
    segmentedControl.tintColor = background
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = background
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentTintColor = selectedColor
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: selectedColor as Any], for: .normal)
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: background as Any], for: .selected)
}
else
{
    segmentedControl.tintColor = background
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = selectedColor
    segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 4
}
```

Comment: This works seemingly for every backgroundColor except .white and .clear. When you set it to either of those two colors what is shown is an ugly gray color.

Comment: @c0d3p03t I think the gray blending is visible with any light color. I'm trying to use a light tan, but I also see it with UIColor.yellow.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. However, you don't need the `as Any` in the dictionary value.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer can be simplified and we can avoid using `DispatchQueue.main.async` call by subclassing `UISegmentedControl` and overriding the `layoutSubviews` method:

```
class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    for i in 0...(numberOfSegments - 1)  {
      subviews[i].isHidden = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using this solution, the dividers between segments disappear in my segmented control. Do you have the same side effect? If not, can you share your configuration of the segmented control?

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 3 & 4+

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31652184/3249196 , if you want an all white background without the grey overlay justr replace `tintColor` and `backgroundColor` with `UIColor.white`

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders() {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: backgroundColor!), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: tintColor!), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    }

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:  1.0, height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
        context!.fill(rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image!
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Carioni, I've actually tried this method before and unless I'm missing something you lose the animation on changing selection which is what I'm trying to maintain. Erick Silva's suggestion while a bit hacky does do the trick.

Comment: @Phil can you share a video example of this? I'm not sure what are you referring to, because I'm not losing any animation

Answer (score 1):

I completed the code of the previous answerer and everything worked for me

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

    func applyWhiteBackgroundColor() {
        // for remove bottom shadow of selected element
        self.selectedSegmentTintColor = selectedSegmentTintColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.99)
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            //just to be sure it is full loaded
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else {
                    return
                }
                for i in 0 ..< (self.numberOfSegments)  {
                    let backgroundSegmentView = self.subviews[i]
                    //it is not enogh changing the background color. It has some kind of shadow layer
                    backgroundSegmentView.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[Modified Segmented Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veTlS.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

`UISegmentedControl` is composed of several subviews. The first subviews are `UIImageView`s that display resizable images to create the UI of each segment. These are the cause of the unexpected gray color. You can hide these image views if you want your background color to be fully visible, just note this will hide the separators you see between segments.

Note that the internal implementation could change in a future iOS version. Other solutions here would crash if the number of subviews changes to be fewer than the number of segments. Here is a safer solution that would not crash and could handle some possible changes to the subviews. While it is still not guaranteed to work in the future, at worst unintended UI elements would get hidden.

```
class CustomSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        baseInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        baseInit()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // The system displays an image view for each segment that is a gray color - hide it to reveal the intended background color
        let imageViews = subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UIImageView }.prefix(numberOfSegments)
        imageViews.forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
    }
    
    private func baseInit() {
        backgroundColor = .white
        selectedSegmentTintColor = .systemFill
    }

}
```

Without hiding subviews:
[image: Screenshot 1]

Hidden subviews:
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score -1):

In Xamarin.iOS this worked for me:

```
class MySegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl
{
    int insertedIndex = 0;

    public override void InsertSubview(UIView view, nint atIndex)
    {
        base.InsertSubview(view, atIndex);

        if (insertedIndex == 2 || insertedIndex == 3)
            view.Hidden = true;

        insertedIndex++;
    }
}
```