# Clear color not working for UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

```
let items = ["About", "Achievement", "Ratings"]
segment = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
segment.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
segment.tintColor = UIColor(red: 247/255, green: 245/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1.0)
segment.selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.white
segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
scrollView.addSubview(segment)
```

[image]

When change background color to clear color or white color its replacing background color with gray

segment.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UISegmentedControl iOS 13 clear color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450865/uisegmentedcontrol-ios-13-clear-color)

Comment: The `setBackgroundImage` line is what you need. Just give it a transparent image.